# DRF serializer doesn't save instance to the db

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

#### Views

```py
class AuthDataViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = AuthData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AuthDataSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_data, headers = create_auth_data(self, request.data, {'request': request})
        # returning response with the data
```

#### create_auth_data function

```py
def create_response_data(view, data: dict = None, context: dict = None):
    # I calling the viewset methods below
    serializer = view.get_serializer(data=data, context=context)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    view.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = view.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

    return serializer.data, headers
```

#### Serializer

```py
class AuthDataSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AuthData
        fields = ('login', 'password', 'project', 'manager')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['manager'] = self.context['request'].user.manager
        return validated_data
```

I got the **correct serializer.data**, no errors and pure data, but the **instance didn't saved** to the database.

Comment: Show your serializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
class AuthDataSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AuthData
        fields = ('login', 'password', 'project', 'manager')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        auth_data = AuthData.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return auth_data
```